# UK Visitor Visa - can I put property value into the answer for how much money we have in savings?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying a standard visitor visa for my parents and I have a query related to one particular question - "How much money do you have in savings (in GBP)?"

My father is retired and my mother is housewife. My father has around 2500 GBP as savings (fixed deposit + savings) in his account.
Can we also show the property value he has registered on his name under this section?

I mean can I put the value like (2500 + property value) in this section OR I have to just put 2500 which is available as a bank balance in his account?

Comment: Is there not a later question about other asset types? AFAIK the question you’re referring to is asking about liquid assets.

Comment: @Traveller : Hi, yes there are other questions but it says  "Another regular income" and then it is sub divided to this question "Total amount of money that you get in a year".
Now my father has a property which is now 20 times the value from what he purchased. Where to show that?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the question you’re referring to relates to liquid assets that help prove the applicant can afford the trip and that the proposed spend is proportionate to their financial situation.

Property ownership helps to prove ties to home country, and to show the overall picture of the applicant’s circumstances. I recommend you state that your father owns property to the value of £xxx in the ‘Extra information’ section at the end of the application, and provide a copy of the property deed along with your father’s other supporting documents.